# Is it possible to replace the CPU on my Asus X200MA?

Tags: laptop, cpu, upgrade, asus-laptop

I have an Asus X200MA and I was wondering if it is capable of getting its CPU replaced or if its current CPU is permanent .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The processor is not replaceable.

The [Intel Celeron N2815](http://ark.intel.com/products/79051/Intel-Celeron-Processor-N2815-1M-Cache-up-to-2_13-GHz) processor installed on this system uses a BGA 1170 package. [BGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array) processors are permanently soldered onto the motherboard and cannot be replaced by the user.

**Edit:** The [Intel Celeron 1007U](http://ark.intel.com/products/72061/Intel-Celeron-Processor-1007U-2M-Cache-1_50-GHz) uses BGA 1023 so it is not replaceable either.

Comment: I believe the processor is an Intel Celeron CPU 1007U... I'm not sure if that is the same as the processor you mentioned, truthfully I'm new at all this technical stuff so I apologize in advance if I'm seem stupid right now.

Comment: Ah ok.. Well thank you I appreciate the help, I'll just have to save up for a better computer.. Thanks again.

Comment: Updated--and nope, that's not replaceable, either.